# Why do we need to import a class if the parent already imports it

Tags: java, android, inheritance

Say I have:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {

    }
}
```

and then I extend that class as such:

```
public class MyNewActivity extends MyActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {

    }
}
```

If I don't include `import android.os.Bundle;` then `MyNewActivity` class won't compile, however it should already know about `Bundle` since the parent class already imports it. What gives?

Comment: `import`s are not inherited.

Comment: `it should already know about Bundle`  - why should it?  `Bundle` is not a member class of MyActivity.

Comment: @Simin The thinking was, since MyNewActivity already inherits all the methods of MyActivity, including method signatures, how would MyNewActivity be able to explicitly or implicitly utilize `Bundle`s?

Comment: If MyActivity never needs to actually know that Bundle is, it can just pass requests through to the Activity in a black box and recieve things back in a black box which it gives to the requester then it doesn't need to know what Bundle is, only if it needs to open the box does it need to import Bundle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, the scope of the import is not the class that is declared, but the file in which the import is given.  So, in a different file, you must still import what you need.

According to the [JLS, Section 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5),

> An import declaration makes types or members available by their simple
>   names only within the compilation unit that actually contains the
>   import declaration.

That is, the scope of the import is the file within which it's located.